# bash quoting issue when using bash -c with more than one argument

Tags: bash, quotes

first I want to apologize for the bad title, my problem is best illustrated through the following example:

This command works fine, although it doesn't make a lot of sense to do so.

```
sudo bash -c 'pwd 2>/dev/null'
```

but when I put it in an variable, and do :

```
COMMAND="sudo bash -c 'pwd 2>/dev/null'"
(set -xv; ${COMMAND})
```

I get the quoting unmatching error:

```
+ sudo bash -c ''\''pwd' '2>/dev/null'\'''
2>/dev/null': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
2>/dev/null': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The problem here seems to be the space between `pwd` and `2>/dev/null`, the following works:

```
COMMAND="sudo bash -c 'pwd'"
(set -xv; ${COMMAND})
```

The problem appears even when I just put a tailing whitespace after `pwd`

What am i doing wrong here? and how do I solve it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: At the risk of overgeneralizing, there is *never* a good reason to embed an entire command in a single string for execution. Explain why you think it is necessary; there is probably a better approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should at least use an array, which acts as a second layer of proper quoting, instead of a flat string:

```
my_command=(sudo bash -c 'pwd 2>/dev/null')
"${my_command[@]}"
```

However, you should rethink why you feel it necessary to store a command like this in the first place. A function is a better idea:

```
my_command () {
    sudo bash -c 'pwd 2> /dev/null'
}

my_command
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment above is correct, you can probably find a better way to do this. But, playing devil's advocate, have you tried `eval` to run the command?

```
COMMAND="sudo bash -c 'pwd 2>/dev/null'"
(set -xv; eval $COMMAND)
```

Comment: No! `eval` is _not_ the answer! especially with unquoted variable expansion!